# sent message appearing several times when i send to multiple recipients

Tags: sinch

i am trying out the sinch SDK for instant messaging. sending messages to one recipient is working OK. however, when i send to say 3 people, the message is delivered but on the side of the sender, it appears 3 times. That means if i create a group of 20 people, the message will appear on the sender's side 20 times.
is there a way to make this code fire only once when i am sending a message to a group?

```
@Override
public void onMessageSent(MessageClient client, Message message, String recipientId) {
    mMessageAdapter.addMessage(message, MessageAdapter.DIRECTION_OUTGOING);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's once line of code that should solve your problem. In the MainViewController.h where the message bubble is added to the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath, check if countOfRecipients (which you have to declare yourself ofcourse) is less than or equal to one, cell should add that particular bubble (which you can get) by calculation of total message bubble rows yet added to tableView. this shall solve the problem!